# Reason for objdump dependence on toolchain

Tags: executable, toolchain, objdump

Why are there separate objdump binaries for different toolchains, something like arm-none-eabi-objdump?

Why can't the objdump executable be used alongwith the particular switch? For example -marm to get the dump about the arm binary?

Comment: Pretty much all the binutils executables (including the compile/link toolchain) are compiled separately for each target platform. The reason you have arm-none-eabi-objdump is the same reason you have arm-none-eabi-gcc and arm-none-eabi-ld.

Answer (score 0):

The binary files for different architectures are interpreted in a different way. So the same binary code will interpret into totally different machine instructions on different CPU architectures. As for objdump, the most clear example can be shown with `--disassemble` switch, which is instructing it to convert the binary into assembly instructions. But the assembly instructions are totally different for different architectures, so the objdump utility has to know the right one.